# UITableViewCell Set Selected Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

trying to figure out how to set the selected image for for a `tableViewCell`.

The old way of writing this was `cell.selectedImage` but that has been deprecated since 3.0.

I've tried numerous things, but can't get it too work.

Thanks!
Josh

Answer (score 24):

According to the [Deprecated UITableViewCell Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectedImage) doc, you should use the imageView's highlightedImage property as a replacement for selectedImage. For example:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected_image.png"];
cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can set selected backgroundView like below....

```
        UIImageView *selBGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urimage.png"]];
                cell.selectedBackgroundView = selBGView;
```

Answer (score 3):

That didn't worked because you might set the normal state image like this

```
cell.imageView.image = ///
```

Try it -  It worked for me perfectly!!

```
UIImageView *selBGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urimage_selected.png"]];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView = selBGView;
[selBGView release];

UIImageView *BGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urimage.png"]];
 cell.backgroundView = BGView;
[BGView release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_call.png"];
    UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];

    [bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 2, 30, 38)];

//Finally give this imageView to the cell

     [cell.contentView addSubview:bgImageView];
```

Hope it will solve your problem !

Comment: Awesome! Thanks dude. The CGRect coords are a bit off, but nothing I can't fix. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Joshua Russell why you had unaccepted the answer....it was accepted by you earlier.....is this not helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Use this one!:

```
selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
cell.selectedBackgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
```