# adding images to UItableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

Is it possible to add images to a table view? To the left side? And if so, what size should it be?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A custom UITableViewCell is not required to simply add an image to the left side of the cell. Simply configure the imageView property of the UITableView cell in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{    
   static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   cell.textLabel.text = @"I'm a UITableViewCell!";
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyReallyCoolImage.png"];

   return cell;
}
```

Unless you provide a tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method in your UITableViewDelegate, the default height of a UITableViewCell is 44 points, which is 44 pixels on a non-retina display and 88 pixels on a retina display.

Comment: @ thomas: it was very helpful and important

Comment: You mention the height of the UITableViewCell itself, the 44 points got nothing to do with size of UIImageView, as asked for..

Comment: @ingenspor, as the cell is 44 points in height, then so will the image view be 44 points tall.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You can take help from [cocoawithlove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html) and [here](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284). These tutorials will give you an idea how to give images to `UITableView`. Finally, as asked before on SO, [UITableViewCell Set Selected Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988777/uitableviewcell-set-selected-image/4988890#4988890).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you can add them wherever you like in the cell. Finally, they should be however big (or small) that makes sense to your application.

Comment: Yeah, see the tableview suite sample code for how to create a custom cell. Place an image view on your custom cell in the position you want it to be in, and when you set up your tableview data source, use this custom view, add the image to the image view, and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** Solution of Thomas answer:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "I'm a UITableViewCell!"
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "MyReallyCoolImage.png")
    return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```