# Adding Image to Table Cell (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, uitableview

I am trying to do something similar to twitter or Facebook.

Answer (score 18):

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{    
   static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   cell.textLabel.text = @"I'm a UITableViewCell!";
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyReallyCoolImage.png"];

   return cell;
}
```

Credit to [Thomas Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577750/thomas-moore)

[adding images to UItableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999017/adding-images-to-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

Well, to add an image to a table cell, you would add a UIImage to the image property of a subtitle UITableViewCell or your own custom Cell. I would read the doc on Customizing UITableViewCells at developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

  cell.textLabel.text = "I'm a UITableViewCell!";
  cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "MyReallyCoolImage.png")

  return cell;
}
```