# iOS Table View Refresh Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I followed the advice in the link below to add images to cells in a table view.

[Adding Image to Table Cell (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212134/adding-image-to-table-cell-ios)

Is there a way to force refresh a cell i.e. add/remove images or indicators?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can call `[self.tableview reloadData];` on the tableview and refresh the entire table.

Otherwise you can do this to refresh a single cell.

```
 [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I tried [self.tableview reloadData] except it doesn't seem to recall the method "- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath" and add the image to the new cells.

Comment: Put an NSLog(@"Method called"); in your `- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` if you want to prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have indexPath of the cell, sometimes this may just do the job

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: If you are just using UITableViewCell and not a custom class there should be no need to cast the UITableViewCell pointer to a UITableViewCell pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [reloadRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) method of the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) class to reload certain rows of the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) instance using a given animation effect.

Note that there are similarly named [insertRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) and [deleteRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows) methods if instead you want to insert or delete certain rows in the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) instance.