# How to replace dictionary inside an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

This is my JSON response

```
data =     {
    Apparels =         (
                    {
            "category_id" = 1650002;
            "category_name" = Apparels;
            "country_id" = 1;
            "created_by" = 1;
            "created_on" = "2016-03-17 13:29:00";
            id = 2;
            "is_checked" = 0;
            "is_delete" = 1;
            "modified_by" = 1;
            "modified_on" = "2016-08-26 05:53:21";
            "short_name" = UP;
            status = 550002;
            value = UP;
        },
                    {
            "category_id" = 1650002;
            "category_name" = Apparels;
            "country_id" = 1;
            "created_by" = 1;
            "created_on" = "2016-03-17 13:29:00";
            id = 3;
            "is_checked" = 0;
            "is_delete" = 1;
            "modified_by" = 1;
            "modified_on" = "2016-08-26 10:41:12";
            "short_name" = "<null>";
            status = 550001;
            value = MP;
        },
                    {
            "category_id" = 1650002;
            "category_name" = Apparels;
            "country_id" = 1;
            "created_by" = 4;
            "created_on" = "2016-04-08 12:10:17";
            id = 4;
            "is_checked" = 0;
            "is_delete" = 1;
            "modified_by" = 1;
            "modified_on" = "2017-03-06 10:35:04";
            "short_name" = HR;
            status = 550002;
            value = Haryana;
        },
                    {
            "category_id" = 1650002;
            "category_name" = Apparels;
            "country_id" = 1;
            "created_by" = 4;
            "created_on" = "2016-04-08 12:10:36";
            id = 5;
            "is_checked" = 0;
            "is_delete" = 1;
            "modified_by" = 1;
            "modified_on" = "2016-08-26 05:53:29";
            "short_name" = HP;
            status = 550002;
            value = "Himachal Pardesh";
        }
    );
};
```

[image]

So far, I am able to create screen like this. I want that user may be able to check and uncheck products. For that I need to replace value of "is_checked" from "0" to "1". This is my code.

```
  detailArr = [responseDict[@"data"] mutableCopy]; //MutableArray
  keys = [responseDict[@"data"] allKeys];//MutableArray

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return detailArr.count;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section{

    NSDictionary *objectDict = [detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:section]];
    return objectDict.count;
  }

  - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
       UILabel *labelVw = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 275, 35)];
      labelVw.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
      labelVw.text = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
      headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      [headerView addSubview:labelVw];
      tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
      return headerView;
  }

  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      return 5;
  }

  - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

     if(![[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] valueForKey:@"is_checked"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"1"])
     {

         cell.titleLbl.text = [[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [cell.checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unchecked Checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [cell.bookmarkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      }else{
         [cell.checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked Checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [cell.bookmarkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         cell.titleLbl.attributedText = [ValidationClass LineOnLabel:[[detailArr valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

      }
   [cell.checkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
   cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

   return cell;

 }


 - (void)actionCheck:(UIButton*)sender{
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
      tagvalue = [ValidationClass getRowByBtn:btn :_tblVw];   //returns indexPath.row by click of button inside cell
      sectionValue = [ValidationClass getSectionByBtn:btn :_tblVw];  //returns section of tableview
      NSMutableDictionary *replaceDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     if([[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] valueForKey:@"is_checked"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue] isEqual:@"1"]){
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue]forKey:@"category_id"];
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue] forKey:@"value"];
         [replaceDict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"is_checked"];
         [detailArr replaceObjectAtIndex:tagvalue withObject:replaceDict];
         [_tblVw reloadData];
         [self addProduct:detailArr andPosition:tagvalue];
    }else{
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue]forKey:@"category_id"];
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue] forKey:@"value"];

        [replaceDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"is_checked"];

        NSMutableArray *arr = [[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] mutableCopy];
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:tagvalue withObject:replaceDict];
        detailArr = [arr mutableCopy]; // this removes previous data and add this. But I want to overwrite the existing data with replace dict at particular index.
        NSLog(@"%@",detailArr);

        [_tblVw reloadData];
        [self addProduct:detailArr andPosition:tagvalue];
   }

   NSLog(@"%@", detailArr);

 }
```

NSLog returns this:

```
    (
        {
        "category_id" = UP;
        "is_checked" = 1;
        value = UP;
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 1650002;
        "category_name" = Apparels;
        "country_id" = 1;
        "created_by" = 1;
        "created_on" = "2016-03-17 13:29:00";
        id = 3;
        "is_checked" = 0;
        "is_delete" = 1;
        "modified_by" = 1;
        "modified_on" = "2016-08-26 10:41:12";
        "short_name" = "<null>";
        status = 550001;
        value = MP;
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 1650002;
        "category_name" = Apparels;
        "country_id" = 1;
        "created_by" = 4;
        "created_on" = "2016-04-08 12:10:17";
        id = 4;
        "is_checked" = 0;
        "is_delete" = 1;
        "modified_by" = 1;
        "modified_on" = "2017-03-06 10:35:04";
        "short_name" = HR;
        status = 550002;
        value = Haryana;
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 1650002;
        "category_name" = Apparels;
        "country_id" = 1;
        "created_by" = 4;
        "created_on" = "2016-04-08 12:10:36";
        id = 5;
        "is_checked" = 0;
        "is_delete" = 1;
        "modified_by" = 1;
        "modified_on" = "2016-08-26 05:53:29";
        "short_name" = HP;
        status = 550002;
        value = "Himachal Pardesh";
    }
)
```

After this, it crashes at numberOfRowsInSection.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post crash log.

Answer (score 0):

the result of this code is NSDictionary,but you create an array object:

`responseDict[@"data"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can discuss with the server, data must be a collection, the format of the NSArray, and now it is a NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistake first of solve it, the mistake is are

1. You are cell design in checkbox button set tag.

   `[cell.checkBtn setTag:indexPath.row];`
2. Manage detect tap action of checkbox button.

   `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = button.tag;`
3. Using this row object to manage replace object.

   A. First you are get the selected object and stored in one NSMutableDictionary object.

   `NSMutableDictionary *dic = [detailArr objectAtIndex:row];`

   B. Replace object as set value.

   `[dic setValue:@"1" forKey:@"is_checked"];`

   C. This replace value changes only - "dic" object, not your selected Cell, so following list is change object in your array list.

   `[detailArr replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:dic];`

   D. And last you have [reload the selected cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560243/5593725) in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because array inside "Apparels" is immutable. I finally found the solution.

```
    detailArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if([responseDict[@"data"] count] > 0){
        keys = [responseDict[@"data"] allKeys];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict1;
        NSMutableArray *arrx;
        for(int i=0;i<[responseDict[@"data"] count];i++){
            arrx=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            arrx = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[responseDict[@"data"] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i] ]];
            dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict1 setObject:arrx forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
           [detailArr addObject:dict1];
          }

     }
   [_tblVw reloadData];
```

Code for checkbox functionality by replacing the dictionary inside JSON response array at particular index.

```
- (void)actionCheck:(UIButton*)sender{
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
      tagvalue = [ValidationClass getRowByBtn:btn :_tblVw];
      sectionValue = [ValidationClass getSectionByBtn:btn :_tblVw];

      NSMutableDictionary *replaceDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
      if([[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"is_checked"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue] isEqual:@"1"]){
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"category_id"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue]forKey:@"category_id"];
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue]forKey:@"id"];
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue] forKey:@"value"];
         [replaceDict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"is_checked"];
         [[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] replaceObjectAtIndex:tagvalue withObject:replaceDict];
         NSLog(@"%@",detailArr);

         [_tblVw reloadData];
         [self addProduct:detailArr andPosition:tagvalue];
    }else{
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"category_id"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue]forKey:@"category_id"];
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue]forKey:@"id"];
         [replaceDict setObject:[[[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] valueForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:tagvalue] forKey:@"value"];

         [replaceDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"is_checked"];
         [[[detailArr valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:sectionValue]] objectAtIndex:sectionValue] replaceObjectAtIndex:tagvalue withObject:replaceDict];

        NSLog(@"%@",detailArr);
        [self addProduct:detailArr andPosition:tagvalue];
    }

        NSLog(@"%@", detailArr);

 }
```