# UITableView image on the left hand side

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding images to UItableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999017/adding-images-to-uitableview)

I want to add image in UITableView in the left hand side how could I add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This ,

```
UIImageView *backgroundCellImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 80)];

    backgroundCellImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];

[cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundCellImage];
[backgroundCellImage release];
```

Answer (score 18):

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
```

and thats it! really easy!

If you are using custom cells then you need to add an ImageView to your custom cell in IB. Then create, connect and synthesize an IBOutlet for it and add this code to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.yourImageOutlet.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath method`..

```
 cell.imageView.image = yourImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can add UIImageView to the desired position by setting its frame...

```
    UIImageView *postImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 34, 300, 225)]; 
    postImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; 
    [postImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]; 
    postImage.clipsToBounds = YES; 
    [cell addSubview:postImage]; 
    [postImage release];
```

or you can go with following code too...

```
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Answer (score 1):

just use :

if you are using **UITableViewCellStyleDefault** then you don't need to customize the look of of tableviewcells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Configure the cell...

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];
cell.textLabel.text=@"Text";
return cell;
}
```

Comment: is the image view the background image or the icon on the left?