# UITableViewCell's IamgeView frame

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to print the UIImageView's frame inside an UITableViewCell , but I am getting as {{0,0},{0,0}}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0f];        
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        //cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, 38, 38);
    }

    NSString *imageName = [[itemsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[itemsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];


    NSLog(@"Image Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect([cell.imageView frame]));

    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I added my markers in your code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0f];        
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        //cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, 38, 38);
    }

    NSString *imageName = [[itemsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    /* EDITED CODE START */
    CGFloat x = cell.imageView.image.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = cell.imageView.image.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = cell.imageView.image.size.width;
    CGFloat height = cell.imageView.image.size.height;
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
    /* EDITED CODE END */

    cell.textLabel.text = [[itemsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];


    NSLog(@"Image Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect([cell.imageView frame]));

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I corrected the following 
    CGFloat x = cell.imageView.image.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = cell.imageView.image.origin.y;
to
    CGFloat x = cell.imageView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = cell.imageView.frame.origin.y;

Comment: [See this]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999017/adding-images-to-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UITableViewCell (BrowseHistoryView)

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (isPhone)
    {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 3, 18.0f, 18.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 15, 18.0f, 18.0f);
    }
}

@end
```